# How to throw error to user when saving post

Tags: custom-post-types, errors

I made a custom post type and on saving its additional data I want to check if I a published post exists by its name. It works alright if there is, but I would like to throw some notice if article is not found.

```
    $post_exists = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $_POST['article_name'] . "' AND post_type = 'post'", 'ARRAY_A');
    if($post_exists)
        update_post_meta($id, 'article_name', strip_tags($_POST['article_name']));
    else
        ???
```

I noticed there is http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error but I dont think that is what I want since debugging is set to false?. Error could be anything - some usual notice would be fine, but even simple javascript alert could be good. 
Currently it tells me that the post is saved with green lights which doesnt seem right
[image: http://s1.postimg.org/kmjjjvuvj/image.jpg]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `admin_notices` hook
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices

For example:

```
function ravs_admin_notice() {
    ?>
    <div class="error">
        <p><?php _e( 'Article with this title is not found!', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

on `publish_{your_custom_post_type}` hook
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

```
function on_post_publish( $ID, $post ) {
    // A function to perform actions when a {your_custom_post_type} is published.
    $post_exists = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $_POST['article_name'] . "' AND post_type = 'post'", 'ARRAY_A');
    if($post_exists)
        update_post_meta($id, 'article_name', strip_tags($_POST['article_name']));
    else
       add_action( 'admin_notices', 'ravs_admin_notice' );
}
add_action(  'publish_{your_custom_post_type}',  'on_post_publish', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

The notice is easy to set via the hook `admin_notices`. You can set on each page a message via this hook.

```
function my_admin_notice() {
    ?>
    <div class="updated">
        <p><?php _e( 'Updated!', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
```

Ping this hook on your else construct.

```
else
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice' );
```

Check inside the function `my_admin_notice()` the post type or use this only on the `publish_{custom_post_type}` Hook.

The color is dependence from the css class.

[image]

You find much more about classes and html in this [helper plugin](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style).